# Silverlight Combobox in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, combobox, telerik

I have defined a data template for a c# class in xaml as follows

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ApplicationTemplate">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <telerik:RadComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                         ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentItem.Apps, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=telerik:RadDataForm}}"
                                         IsEnabled="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanInverterConverter}}" />                   
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
```

My "Apps" Enumerable is composed of this object:

```
public class InteractiveApplicationModel : ValidatingModel
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get { return GetProperty(() => Name); }
            set { SetProperty(() => Name, value); }
        }

        public string Type
        {
            get { return GetProperty(() => Type); }
            set { SetProperty(() => Type, value); }
        }

        public string URL
        {
            get { return GetProperty(() => URL); }
            set { SetProperty(() => URL, value); }
        }

        public string Image
        {
            get { return GetProperty(() => Image); }
            set { SetProperty(() => Image, value); }
        }

        public InteractiveApplicationModel()
        {
            this.Type = string.Empty;
            this.Name = string.Empty;
            this.URL = string.Empty;
            this.Image = string.Empty;
        }

        public InteractiveApplicationModel(string name, string type, string url, string image)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Type = type;
            this.URL = url;
            this.Image = image;
        }
    }
}
```

In the View model i have:

```
public IList<InteractiveApplicationModel> Apps
        {
            get
            {
                return new List<InteractiveApplicationModel>()
                    {
                        new InteractiveApplicationModel(null,null,null,null),
                        new InteractiveApplicationModel("name","type","url","image"),
                        new InteractiveApplicationModel("name2","type2","url2","image2")
                    };
            }
        }
```

I then have a form page which loads "complex" objects which contain "InteractiveApplicationModel" objects and use the data template to display those objects.

Everything is working except one thing. I need the selected value of the combobox to be the same as the value of the "InteractiveApplicationModel" objects in my "complex" objects.

My "complex" objects can have up to 5 "InteractiveApplicationModel" objects inside them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Bind the SelectedItem property on the RadComboBox

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedInteractiveApplicationModel, [.... ancestor ....] Mode=TwoWay}"
```

with a Selected property on the ViewModel

```
public InteractiveApplicationModel SelectedInteractiveApplicationModel
    {
        get { return GetProperty(() => SelectedInteractiveApplicationModel); }
        set { SetProperty(() => SelectedInteractiveApplicationModel, value); }
    }
```

Comment: The thing is, there is no "selectedItem", there is a complex object with multiple instances of the InteractiveApplicationModel class and for each of these the form page displays one combobox (in this case it's 5 comboboxes) with the selected item corresponding to the value of the "InteractiveApplicationModel" (this last part is what i'm trying to achieve).

Comment: If you want to get the SelectedItem on the VIewModel side, you need at minimum an InteractiveApplicationModel Property to bind to...